# White labeling React Native apps

Tags: react-native, white-labelling

There is some information here already: [White labeling an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646628/white-labeling-an-ios-app/)

I was wondering if there any workflows for white labeling a React Native app?

Basically if I had a core app for the app store. I would like to create white labeled versions (iOS + Android) with some modifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the project a project called [white-label-app](https://github.com/hazmi/white-label-app) in github, I believe you can inspire yourself looking this project closer (and use them as boilerplate).

I'll try to use the [majorajs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/majorajs), the idea of this package is "*Manage white-label or skinned versions of your React Native app*", sounds good for me.

Comment: Did you try using MajoraJS, Duke? And if so what was your experience with it?

Comment: How would you install multiple com.whitelabelapp ids in one mobile app?? Theming is not an issue for me but I am looking for dynamic selection/configuration of app ids??

Comment: @TamRock I changed my work weeks after my comment, I don't use majorajs proper, but today maybe I believe use the Android flavors and Xcode targers, it's the best option, this post explain it https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-android-like-product-flavors-in-react-native-39b6c011061b

Comment: @prabhat I can't understand very well your problem :/

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of the React Native Bridge & product-flavors/targets to achieve what you want.

The process is extensive to setup, but once you have it setup it is very easy to add new white labelled apps to it.

I wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/react-native-white-label-101-163c1967c12a) that goes over every detail if you need a step by step guide.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) together with [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) to provide values from the environment.

I wrote up a more detailed blog post about it here that explains my approach:

[A React Native White Labeling Journey](https://yehudacohen.medium.com/a-react-native-white-labeling-journey-587469ee7e12)

I'm building the app through the CI which runs my Fastlane script, which parses the unique git tags for each app, building the appropriate app and distributing it to AppStore / GooglePlay.